# matplotlib, show candle value at yaxis label

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I display current price (last candle value) at the right label of yaxis?
Also, is it possible to display candle value next to it?

```
# Read data
data = pd.read_csv('candlestick_python_data.csv')
ohlc = data.loc[:, ['ts', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c']]
ohlc['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(ohlc['ts'], unit='ms')
ohlc['ts'] = ohlc['ts'].apply(mpl_dates.date2num)
ohlc = ohlc.astype(float)


# Creating Subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=0.003, colorup='green', colordown='red', alpha=0.8)

# Setting labels & titles
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
fig.suptitle(pair)

# Formatting Date
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

#ohlc['SMA5'] = ohlc['c'].rolling(5).mean()
#ax.plot(ohlc['ts'], ohlc['SMA5'], color='green', label='SMA5')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

What I want:
[image]
What I have:
[image]

Comment: You might want to look into [`annotations`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html).

Comment: @mapf thank you for link, it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
el = Ellipse((2, -1), 0.5, 0.5)
ax.add_patch(el)
ax.annotate(last_price, (dateTimeXaxis, last_price),
            xytext=(35, 0), textcoords='offset points',
            size=10, va="center",
            bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc=(0.0, 0.7, 0.7), ec="none"),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple",
                            fc=(0.0, 0.7, 0.7), ec="none",
                            patchA=None,
                            patchB=el,
                            relpos=(0.5, 0.5)))
```

[image]